# Добавление свойств элемента JavaFX через FXML

Tags: java, javafx

Допустим у меня есть AnchorPane на которую в рантайме будет добавляться кнопка. Как мне сделать так, чтобы все свойства кнопки загружались из отдельного FXML файла?  Нагуглил только фабрику контроллеров, но почемуто уверен, что есть способ тривиальнее. Спасибо!

Comment: Из `FXML` никак. В `FXML` может быть только структура для отображения.

Comment: Возможно отдельный FXML для кнопки описанный как  <fx:root type="javafx.scene.control.Button"> прокатит.